# Show all pandas dataframes in an IPython Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

How could I identify all the Pandas DataFrames created in my current notebook session?

Something like in SAS seeing all the members in the Work library would be ideal.

Thanks.

Comment: Pandas DataFrames where? In memory? On your disk? Saved how? Need more input!

Comment: Within the context of a ipython notebook session  - memory.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Solution

```
%who DataFrame
```

## Explanation

### All objects

> ... seeing all the members in the Work library would be ideal.

```
In [1]:

a = 10
b = 'abs'
c = [1, 2, 3]
```

`%who` shows all used names:

```
In [2]:
%who
a    b   c
```

Conveniently as a list:

```
In [3]:
%who_ls

Out[3]:
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Or as table with data types:

```
In [4]:
%whos

Variable   Type    Data/Info
----------------------------
a          int     10
b          str     abs
c          list    n=3
```

## Filter for DataFrames

```
In [5]:
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [100, 200, 300]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b': [100, 200, 300]})

In [6]:
%whos DataFrame

Variable   Type         Data/Info
---------------------------------
df1        DataFrame         a\n0  100\n1  200\n2  300
df2        DataFrame         b\n0  100\n1  200\n2  300

In [7]:

%who DataFrame
df1  df2

In [8]:
%who_ls DataFrame

Out[8]:
['df1', 'df2']
```

Comment: This seriously made my day. I always forget about those incredibly useful `%` statements.

Comment: And now I know their name? TGIF indeed!

Comment: Great thanks Mike - that's more succinct than proc datasets!

Answer (score 5):

If you mean memory try something like:

```
for i in dir():
    if type(globals()[i]) == pandas.DataFrame:
        print(i)
```

or some such.