# Pandas Get a List Of All Data Frames loaded into memory

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to read several csv files into memory for processing and at some point would like to list all the data frames I have loaded into memory. Is there a simple way to do that? (I am thinking something like %ls but only for the data frames that I have available in memory)

Comment: Are you capturing these dataframes in seperate variables, or in a container of some kind?

Comment: Each file is loaded as a separate variable.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could list all dataframes with the following:

```
import pandas as pd

# create dummy dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : list(range(100))})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : list(range(100))})

# check whether all variables in scope are pandas dataframe. 
# Dir() will return a list of string representations of the variables. 
# Simply evaluate and test whether they are pandas dataframes
alldfs = [var for var in dir() if isinstance(eval(var), pd.core.frame.DataFrame)]

print(alldfs) # df1, df2
```

Comment: But this seems to create a list where "df1" and "df2" appear as strings. When you I try to execute some operation on them, I get the error: "TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'str'> was passed"

Comment: @SMJune I have added a answer which solves this issue.

Answer (score 32):

I personally think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949786/show-all-pandas-dataframes-in-an-ipython-notebook) approach is much better (if in ipython).

```
import pandas as pd
%whos DataFrame
```

Comment: this seems to be the cleanest solution

Comment: this is really nice, but is also a nice way to save the output from whos into a variable some saveable form

Answer (score 9):

building on previous answers ...
this returns a list

```
import pandas as pd 
%who_ls DataFrame
```

however, if you try to run a script it doesn't work

thus

```
import pandas as pd
sheets=[]    
for var in dir():
    if isinstance(locals()[var], pd.core.frame.DataFrame)  and var[0]!='_':
        sheets.append(var)
```

since some DataFrames will have a copy for internal use only and those start with '_'

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to have all the dataframes in a list which is iterable, you want to concatenate all dataframes, and their number will grow or names are going to change this is the way

```
#Output all the dataframe
alldfs = [var for var in dir() if isinstance(eval(var), pd.core.frame.DataFrame)]

#Create a list of iterable dataframes
list_of_dfs = []

for df in alldfs:
    list_of_dfs.append(locals()[df])
```

In case you have multiple dataframes, and there are ones which you dot not want to concatenate or perform other operations, you can put them in small dataframe, filter them and chose the desired ones.