# list variables in memory using function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to create a utility function that filters variables in my current environment and prints them (ie print all variables that have type `pd.core.frame.DataFrame`) and then put this function in my utils module. I used ([Pandas Get a List Of All Data Frames loaded into memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113663/pandas-get-a-list-of-all-data-frames-loaded-into-memory)):

```
import pandas as pd
def list_my_frames():
    f = [var for var in dir() if isinstance(eval(var), pd.core.frame.DataFrame)]
    return f
```

I would like to be able to pass my current environment to `dir()` so that I can use it outside of my utils module. How can I get a handle to my current environment in python?

Comment: why not create a function that accepts the product of `dir()` ?

Comment: plus use `vars()` instead of `dir()` no need for `eval`.

Comment: is there a way to simply pass a handle to the scope in which `list_my_frames` is being evaluated in and then pass that on to `dir`? ie `list_my_frames(my_scope): ...dir(my_scope)`?