# How can I loop over all Pandas Data Frames in the workspace?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to be able to iterate over all data frames (not the names!) that are currently in the workspace.

To get a list of all data frames I found the following solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113663/pandas-get-a-list-of-all-data-frames-loaded-into-memory):

```
import pandas as pd

# create dummy dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : list(range(100))})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : list(range(100))})

# check whether all variables in scope are pandas dataframe. 
# Dir() will return a list of string representations of the variables. 
# Simply evaluate and test whether they are pandas dataframes
alldfs = [var for var in dir() if isinstance(eval(var), pd.core.frame.DataFrame)]

print(alldfs) # df1, df2
```

This works as described, but the problem is that I would like to be able to use this list to iterate over the actual data frames, **not the names** of the data frames.

The following code returns the length of the names of the data frames but should return the length of the data frames (number of lines):

```
for df in alldfs:
    print(len(df))
```

It should return:

```
100
100
```

It returns:

```
3
3
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will yield the output you want as `dict`:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : list(range(100))})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : list(range(100))})

alldfs = {key: value for key, value in locals().items() if isinstance(value, pd.core.frame.DataFrame)}

#or using your method

alldfs = {var: eval(var) for var in dir() if isinstance(eval(var), pd.core.frame.DataFrame)}

print(alldfs) 

for df in alldfs.values():
    print(len(df))
```

Output:

```
{'df1':     Col1
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
..   ...
95    95
96    96
97    97
98    98
99    99

[100 rows x 1 columns], 'df2':     Col1
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
..   ...
95    95
96    96
97    97
98    98
99    99

[100 rows x 1 columns]}
100
100
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `eval` on the elements of your list, because those are the **names** of your **dataframe variables**. i.e :

```
for df in alldfs:
    print(len(eval(df)))
```

Comment: [`eval is evil`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/4985099), it's usage is discouraged. Rather better option would be ``dict`` based one recommended by @adnanmuttaleb.

Comment: Alright , Thanks man . Will keep this in mind in future !