# Write all pandas dataframe in workspace to excel

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to write all the currently available pandas dataframe in workspace to excel sheets. By following example from this [SO thead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41113663), but I'm unable to make it work.

This is my not working code:

```
alldfs = {var: eval(var) for var in dir() if isinstance(eval(var), pd.core.frame.DataFrame)}
for df in alldfs.values():
    print(df.name)
    fmane = df+".xlsx"
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fmane)
    df.to_excel(writer)
    writer.save()
```

Any help on how to correct this, so that I can pass the dataframe names to a variable, so that the excel filename being written can be same as the dataframe. I'm using spyder 4, python 3.8

Comment: `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'` <-- this is the error I get, you should iterate through the keys and values from the dict you are creating in the first line and use the keys as a name. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small fix will do the job:

```py
alldfs = {var: eval(var) for var in dir() if isinstance(eval(var), pd.core.frame.DataFrame)}
for df_name, df in alldfs.items():
    print(df_name)
    fmane = df_name+".xlsx"
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fmane)
    df.to_excel(writer)
    writer.save()
```