# Get dataframe to Excel via Python, ONLY if name starts P20

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, filenames, converters

I have a lot dataframes ( created in previous script) all starts with P20 (names). They Are not save in aby folders, just as variables in script.
I need to select those dataframes And convert to excel with same name.
Ie

```
For each dataframe.name like  (P20*)
Dataframes.to_excel(dataframe.nale.xlsx)`
```

I assume i need to use some global function but i am not familiar with that.
Can you please help me with that?
Thank you

Comment: what did you try? Do you know `os.listdir()` and later `if filename.startswith("P20"): ...`. OR `glob.glob("P20*")` ?

Comment: If you're talking about in-memory dataframes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113663/pandas-get-a-list-of-all-data-frames-loaded-into-memory

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use `os.listdir()` and `.startswith()`

```
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    if filename.startswith("P20"):

       old_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)

       df = pd.read_csv(old_path)

       #new_path = old_path.replace(".csv", ".xlsx")
       new_path = old_path + ".xlsx"

       df.to_excel( new_path )
```

Other method is `glob.glob()`

```
for old_path in glob.glob(folder + "/P20*"):

    df = pd.read_csv(old_path)

    #new_path = old_path.replace(".csv", ".xlsx")
    new_path = old_path + ".xlsx"

    df.to_excel( new_path )
```